# JS - How to use an attribute from another function?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use a variable in `function2` I declared on `function1`. I know this is impossible as it is said, but it's the idea.

I thought of creating a class, the thing is that I'll have to instanciate it and send it from all over my program because I call this methods everywhere. I also tried globals, but could not make it work. (I'm new at Javascript)

Do you have advice or best practices in these cases ?

Here is an example:

```
window.onload = function() {
   fct1();
}  

function fct1() {

   var myArray = [];

   myArray.push(new Vehicle("car"));
   myArray.push(new Vehicle("bicycle"));
   myArray.push(new Vehicle("motorcycle"));
}

function fct2() {
   myArray[0].buy(); // buy() is a method of Vehicle. It throws me "myArray is undefined"
}
```

I know this is completely normal, I just don't know how to handle this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is scope.

`myArray` only exists in `fct1` function

```
var myArray = [];

function fct1() {

   myArray.push(new Vehicle("car"));
   myArray.push(new Vehicle("bicycle"));
   myArray.push(new Vehicle("motorcycle"));
}

function fct2() {
   myArray[0].buy(); // buy() is a method of Vehicle.
}
```

Comment: I know, but when I do as you say, it throws me : `Impossible to get "buy" from a null or undefined reference`

Comment: @Elfayer Probably `Vechile()` is also out of the scope of `fct1()`.

Comment: That is because you should call `fct1` before `fct2` or initialize `myArray` with at least an instance of `Vehicle`

Comment: @aduch I'm calling fct1 at `window.onload()`

Comment: Are you calling fct1 before you call fct2?

Comment: @Elfayer Maybe you should show us more of your code then

Comment: It does. And it leads me to find the problem. You couldn't see it in my example, and I thought the problem would come from it. It's because aduch told me that the code was correct that I started to look somewhere else.I used a wrong index. I sended a string instead of a number. My mistake =/